# mongodb need to populate a new field with an old fields value, without destroying other data

Tags: mongodb

I have a situation where a model changed at some point in time and I am faced with (for argument sake) half my data liks like this

```
{
    _id: OID,
    things: [{
        _id:OID,
        arm: string,
        body: string
    }],
    other: string
}
```

and the other half of my data look like this

```
{
    _id: OID,
    things: [{
        _id:OID,
        upper_appendage: string,
        body: string
    }],
    other: string
}
```

I would like to 'correct' half of the data - so that I DON'T have to accommodate both names for 'arm' in my application code.

I have tried a couple different things:
The first errors

```
db.getCollection('x')
.find({things:{$exists:true}})
.forEach(function (record) {
  record.things.arm = record.things.upper_appendage;
  db.users.save(record);
});
```

and this - which destroys all the other data in

```
db.getCollection('x')
.find({things:{$exists:true}})
.forEach(function (record) {
  record.things = {
    upper_appendage.arm = record.things.upper_appendage
  };
  db.users.save(record);
});
```

Keeping in mind that there is other data I want to maintain...
How can I do this???

Comment: In the first approach, Your `things` is an array, so `record.things.arm` will give you error. You should have another for loops to do what you want.

Comment: So in other words you want to replace the field `upper_appendage` with the `arm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `$rename` operator should have worked for this job but unfortunately it doesn't seem to support nested array fields (as of mongodb server 4.2). instead you'd need a `forEach` like the following:

```java
db.items.find({
    things: {
        $elemMatch: {
            arm: {
                $exists: true
            }
        }
    }
}).forEach(function(item) {
    for (i = 0; i != item.things.length; ++i)
     {
        item.things[i].upper_appendage = item.things[i].arm;
        delete item.things[i].arm; ;
    }

    db.items.update({
        _id: item._id
    }, item);
})
```

**note:** i've assumed you want to make all records have `upper_appendage`and get rid of 'arm' field. if it's the other way you want, just switch things around.